# Which carbocation is more stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, aromatic-compounds, stability, resonance

Which one of Tropylium cation (cycloheptatrienyl carbocation) and Cyclopropylmethyl carbocation is more stable? Several references present opposing views on this topic, hence the confusion. Reasons with proper explanation will be appreciated.

Furthermore, is it possible to decide relative carbocation stability using experimental data? If yes, how?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/19162/9961 answers this

Comment: No, it didn't answer me. I'm looking for stability comparison between Tropylium cation and Cyclopropylmethyl cation.