# Why is cyclopropylmethyl radical opening so fast?

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, reactivity, radicals

Ring opening of the cyclopropylmethyl radical is [reliable and fast](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1993/CS/CS9932200347), and so has been used as a radical trap and a [radical clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_clock).

Could someone please explain what exactly makes this reaction so fast, besides the ring strain? Why is the anionic ring opening slower?

[image]

Comment: Cyclopropylmethyl radical undergoes a very rapid ring opening rearrangement that relieves the ring strain and is enthalpically favorable. The rate-constant for this reaction is 8.6×107 s−1 at 298 K.

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan Thanks! But why is the anionic process much slower?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/what-is-the-reason-for-the-exceptional-stability-of-the-cyclopropylmethyl-carboc