# Mechanism for the conversion of an unsaturated alkyl halide to an alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

**Question:**

> Predict the mechanism for the following reaction:
>
> [image: conversion of an unsaturated alkyl halide to an alcohol]

**Attempt:**

I thought it will proceed through S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism as $\ce{H_2O}$ is involved (solvolysis). So I proceeded with the formation of a primary carbocation, which then rearranges via 1,2 methyl shift. Then the nucleophilic attack of $\ce{OH^{-}}$ leads to the following product, which is different form the required one.

Can any further steps lead to the required product or am I wrong from the start (most probably)?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, this reaction does not appear in the literature. So, whether it actually forms the product or not is anybody's guess.

However, if I had to suggest a mechanism... I would note first that an S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction on a primary centre, as you have proposed, is difficult. I think it more likely that the alkene assists in the expulsion of the chloride.

[image: Loss of chloride]

The resulting cyclopropylmethyl carbocation is [stabilised](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19090/16683) and is electrophilic at multiple sites. I have only drawn one resonance form, but there are a few more. Attack of water at the tertiary carbon leads to the desired product after deprotonation.

[image: Formation of desired product]