# Where will halogenation take place?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

> In the following halogenation reaction:
>   [image]
>
> **At which position will halogenation take place?**

It is obvious that the halogenation will take place at a 3° Carbon atom (the rates of halogenation for 3°,2°,1° atoms follow the ratio 1600:82:1 or thereabouts). **The question is which 3° atom?** I labeled the atoms as shown:

[image]

I believe that halogenation will take place at **A** because the cyclopropyl ring can stabilize the free radical formed at A better than the 6-membered ring. A similar question that deals with carbocations is [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/what-is-the-reason-for-the-exceptional-stability-of-the-cyclopropylmethyl-carboc), which shows the stability of the cyclopropylmethyl carbocation. Can a similar logic also be applied to free radicals? Please confirm.

Comment: What do you know about the stability of cyclopropyl radicals?

Comment: @Waylander they are more stable than 3° radicals

Comment: And they ring open

Comment: @Waylander I did not know that.

Comment: I'll try to answer this on my own using the first page of this as reference: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1993/cs/cs9932200347/unauth#!divAbstract

Comment: Cyclopropyl methyl radical is different from cyclopropyl radical. Why one C-H bond and not the other? Do bond angles play some role?