# Why does this ring contraction take place in the following nucleophilic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

While attempting this problem I thought that P1 would simply be Bromine getting substituted by OH through nucleophilic substitution.

P2 would give a product formed through ring expansion as a 4 membered ring would tend to rearrange to a 5 membered ring due to strain factors.(SN1 reaction(acidic conditions))

This is the mechanism I thought of:

[image]

This pointed towards option (2) but what's given is option (3).
Why does this happen?

It could be that the four-membered ring being strained rearranges, as Waylander suggests but if it would rearrange, why would it rearrange into a 3 membered ring?
Usually, this happens only when there is a stabilising factor and the only stabilising factor related to a 3 membered ring I can think of, is sigma bond resonance(Dancing resonance)

I would appreciate an explanation of what's happening here.

Comment: Cyclobutanes are very highly strained, more strained than cyclopropanes. If they can rearrange they will.

Comment: Even into three membered rings? I thought three membered are even more strained... Does dancing resonance(sigma resonance) operate here?

Comment: Can the 'close' voters give some feedback about the post? I have edited it to make the post more clear but I would still appreciate some constructive criticcism so that I can improve.

Comment: @ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403900703820 This might be helpful.(Or not it is behind the paywall :/)(There is a first page preview though.)

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari If you wish you can add the mechanism which you think should be followed regarding the question in focus. :=)

Comment: @Rishi Done! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari dancing resonance is not an officially accepted term for cyclopropyl methyl carbocation, stick to sigma resonance in the future.

Comment: @napstablook Alright! Sorry for that, I'm a student so don't have much idea about all that and during the lectures, my teacher usually uses these terms without worrying about 'accepted' terms. I will take care in the future :)

Comment: What software/website do you use to draw chemical structures and reactions and upload them here as an image? Would be of immense help to me. Thanks!

Comment: @TRC I have heard of chemdraw/ Chemdoodle, etc. The other more experienced members might be able to help you out with that. Here, I just used the 'preview' utility that MacOS provides since I didn't have access to any other chem structure tool.

Comment: Why did this get closed though? I provided all my approaches, thoughts, even added a mechanism that I used, what else should I have provided to make this a better post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This reaction should be leaning towards S<sub>N</sub>1 because the approach of $\ce{H2O}$ for a back attack to the ABMO of the $\ce{C-Br}$ is heavily hindered since the neighborhood is congested due to the small ring of cyclobutane.

Once cation formation occurs the reaction will interestingly, result in a ring contraction because the carbocation formed would be very stable due to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/what-is-the-reason-for-the-exceptional-stability-of-the-cyclopropylmethyl-carbocdue%20to) kind of resonance.

After the ring contraction the reaction would proceed in a fairly standard nucleophilic attack by $\ce{H2O}$ resulting in the $P_1$ your answer key alludes to. The overall reaction should proceed in the manner shown below:-

[image]