why tricyclopropyl methyl carbocation the most stable carbocation
Triphenyl carbocation has 36 resonance structures, but Tropylium carbocation which has 7 structures is more stable than triphenyl carbocation and cyclopropyl methyl carbocation is more stable and as the number of cyclopropyl group increases the stability increases.
what is the explanation for the above observation. or is the above observation even true?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/what-is-the-reason-for-the-exceptional-stability-of-the-cyclopropylmethyl-carboc

What people even have about this cation? From the amount of q. one wouldn't guess it's something rather exotic.

@Mithoron, or a test question on a wide-spread curriculum. ;-)
